# JavaFX - accessing a dyinamically created tab's controller

Tags: java, javafx, controller, javafx-2, fxml

I have a stage that has a `TabPane tabPane` inside it, with one "main" tab and a `HashMap<Connection,Tab> connectionTabs` of other tabs (`Connection` is a custom class).

I implement those tabs dynamically.

```
@Override
public void connectionCreatedEvent(Connection connection) {
    try {
        Tab tab = new Tab();
        //...
        tab.setContent(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/connectionTab.fxml")));
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
            tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab);
        });
        connectionTabs.put(connection, tab);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, in the `connectionTab.fxml` I declare a controller (`ConnectionTabController`).

How can I access this tabs controller from this class? Or do I have to it another way?

I'm stuck at:

```
@Override
public void connectionLogEvent(Connection connection, String msg) {
    System.out.println("-t-connection log : " + connection + " : " + msg);
    for(Object o : connectionTabs.entrySet()) {
        Map.Entry ct = (Map.Entry)o;
        if(ct.getKey() == connection)
            /* ???(Tab)ct.getKey().getController();??? */
    }
}
```

It's only logical to me that it's somewhere within the `Content` (since I'm setting it up earlier), but I still can't find out how to reach it, or if it's even possible.

Any sort of help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the controller when you load the FXML:

```
try {
    Tab tab = new Tab();
    //...
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../fxml/connectionTab.fxml"));
    tab.setContent(loader.load());

    ConnectionTabController controller = loader.getController();

    // ...
}
```

and then just store it or pass it to wherever it's needed.

Another option might be to use [this pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components). In this case you would do:

```
public class ConnectionTab extends Tab {

    // @FXML-annotated controls...


    public ConnectionTab() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../fxml/connectionTab.fxml"));
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.load();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // controller methods, etc...
}
```

Update your fxml as

```xml
<!-- imports etc ommitted -->

<!-- note no fx:controller.... -->
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.control.Tab" xmlns:fx="...">
    <content>
        <!-- layout here -->
    </content>
</fx:root>
```

And now in your other code you do

```
@Override
public void connectionCreatedEvent(Connection connection) {
    try {
        ConnectionTab tab = new ConnectionTab();
        //...

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
            tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab);
        });
        connectionTabs.put(connection, tab);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now the `connectionTabs` map gives you direct access to the controller methods via the value objects in it.

Note that with this solution, it's very easy to pass references to the `ConnectionTab`, if you need that:

```
public class ConnectionTab {

    private final Connection connection ;

    // ...

    public ConnectionTab(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection ;
        try {

            // load FXML as before...

        } catch (Exception e) { ... }

    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Alright, so it wouldn't be spaghetti if I created another class `ControllerTab` that simply stores (get+set) a tab and its controller and change the `HashMap` to `HashMap<Connection, ControllerTab>`? This is something that did cross my mind, but I thought there might be an easier way to reach a controller.

Comment: Maybe consider a class `ControllerTab extends Tab` which loads the FXML itself and uses [this pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components). That way you just put those in your map and you can access controller methods directly through them, or add/remove them from the tab pane (since they are tabs, etc).

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! Many points to you sir. I think I'll do that, seams logical enough.

Comment: Updated answer to flesh out that idea a bit. Should have called it `ConnectionTab`, not `ControllerTab` in the previous comment.

Comment: Yeah, funny enough, I *did* call it `ConnectionTab`. Thanks for the edit! This is similar to what I had in mind, but it never crossed me to create a class it's own controller.